# How to repeat a substitution the number of times the search word occurs in a row in a substitution command in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

I would like to use tabs in a code that doesn’t use them. What I did until now to implement tabs was pretty handcrafty:

```
:%s/^  /\t/g
:%s/^\t  /\t\t/g
. . .
```

**Question:** Is there a way to replace two spaces (  ) by tab (`\t`) the number of times it was found at the beginning of a line?

Comment: Doesn't this work? `:%s/  /\t/g` ?

Comment: You can also use the `:retab` command. Say `:set ts=2 noet` and then `:retab!`. Then reset tabstop to the value you want to use, eg. `:set ts=4`

Comment: @glts: I'd enter this comment as answer to get rep (because this is exactly what the OP wants)!

Comment: @eckes: yes and no ;) I'd like to know how this work to also use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) three substitution techniques relevant to this case.

**1.** The first one takes advantage of the preceding-atom matching
syntax to naturally define a step of indentation. According to the
question statement, an indent step is a pair of adjacent space
characters preceded with nothing but spaces from the beginning
of line. Following this definition, one can construct the actual
substitution pattern, right to left:

```
:%s/\%(^ *\)\@<=  /\t/g
```

Indeed, the pattern designates an occurrence of two literal space
characters, but only when they are preceded by a zero-width match
of the atom just before `\@<=`, which is the pattern `^ *` wrapped in
grouping parentheses `\%(`, `\)`. These non-capturing parentheses are
used instead of the usual capturing ones, `\(`, `\)`, since there is no
need in further referring to the matched string of leading spaces. Due
to the `g` flag, the above `:substitute` command runs through the
leading spaces pair by pair, and replaces each of them by single tab
character.

**2.** The second technique takes a different approach. Instead of
matching separate indent levels, one can break each of the lines
starting with space characters down into two lines: one containing
the indenting spaces of the original line, and another holding the
rest of it. After that, it is straightforward to replace all of the pairs
of spaces on the first line, and concatenate the lines back together:

```
:g/^ /s/^ \+/&\r/|-s/  /\t/g|j!
```

**3.** The third idea is to process leading spaces by means of Vim
scripting language. A convenient way of doing that is to use the
substitute with an expression feature of the `:substitute` command
(see `:help sub-replace-\=`). When started with `\=`, the substitute
string of the command enables to substitute the matches of a pattern
with results of evaluation of the expression specified after `\=`:

```
:%s#^ \+#\=repeat("\t",len(submatch(0))/2)
```

Comment: Some words of explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Thought more of what `\%`, `\@<=` and stuff like this stands for. I'd really like to learn from your answer, not just copy and paste it. Thanks!

Comment: This is really nice. I don't understand why `\@<=` works while `\zs` doesn't, though. Any insight?

Comment: @Tom:  That is because of heuristic used in the `\@<=` atom implementation for speeding up matching of patterns containing this atom.  *'The part of the pattern after `\@<=` and `\@<!` are checked for a match first'*, as stated in Vim documentation (see `:help /\@<=`).  When `\zs` is used in the pattern instead of `\@<=`, the usual left-to-right matching order does not change, leaving us with the only match for each line.

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to convert spaces into tabs (or vice-versa) <del>at the start of a line</del>, there's the useful `:retab` command which takes care of that. For example:

- `:retab! 2` will convert spaces in groups of two to tabs
- `:set expandtab` and then `:retab! 2` will convert tabstops (of width 2) back to spaces

See `:h :retab` (and `:h 'ts'`) for the details.

This is not a general solution for the original problem, but I think it covers the most common use case.

Comment: @gits: as stated in the comments to my question: This will change ALL tabs to spaces. That's not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: You're right. I see your problem now. Now I'm curious to see a working solution, too ...

Comment: @glts:  Take a look at the command listed in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9885445/254635).

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way of doing this using :s regex's. You can't make the `/g` modifier look backwards otherwise it'd be unusable, and you can't reliably check that you're at the beginning of the line without looking backwards.

The only way of doing it generally is to loop, like so:

```
:for i in range(100)
:   %s/^\t*\zs  /\t/e
:endfor
```

Which is ugly, slow and highly unrecommended. Use `:retab`

Comment: Thanks, but as already said, retab is not a nice option, since it effects all tabs in the file.

Comment: If retab isn't what you want, use the for loop substitution I provided. That really is the only way to replace only the characters at the start of the line, as I explained.